# Polynomial Regression Intuition

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I am taking following *Andrew Ng*'s machine learning course and have just gotten to the *polynomial regression*. I have a hard time understanding the intuition of how it works and how the model equation is formulated mathematically. I was wondering if anyone can provide me with better clarity on this subject.

In addition to this, in his example and many other examples I have seen online, only use uni-variate$(x_1)$ polynomial regression. Is it possible to use multiple features $(x_1, x_2, x_3, ...)$ when using polynomial regression? If so how would it be done? Is it also possible that one feature has a linear relationship while another does not?

Comment: This post might be helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406975/polynomial-regression-using-python also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988082/multivariate-polynomial-regression-with-numpy